# how install library for creating a voice app

Tags: vonage

I  tried to create a voice app, I  following Nexmo guide but
I got some error.

First I tried to Install the library and got an error and then to Initialize the library

```
    // We're creating a Java Application:
    apply plugin: 'application'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    // Download dependencies from Maven Central:
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }

      // Install the Nexmo Client library:
    dependencies {
      compile 'com.nexmo:client:2.0.1'
      compile 'com.nexmo:client:4.+'

}

       // We'll create this class to contain our code:
        mainClassName = "getstarted.SendSMS"
```

- What went wrong:

  ```
  Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
  ```

Comment: What guide are you following?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hLXh1fC0DyeEanXknoyMx75ipjnNrhmn/view?usp=sharing
I  add it to existing Send sms code
https://dashboard.nexmo.com/getting-started/voice